# How can we add superscript in html page?

Tags: html

```
 <td>20<sup>o</sup>C</td>
```

is not giving the output with 'o' as super script. 
How can we add superscript in html page? 
I am getting the output as

20oC only!!

Comment: `sup` is the correct tag. What stylesheets are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `&deg;` to get the ° symbol.

P.S. `<sup>` should have worked.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't make the text superscript but it will meet your needs for this occasion

```
<td>20&deg;C</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Superscripts in HTML can be implied using the  tag. Do it as this :

```html
x<sup>2</sup>+2x+1
```